# Can't access new partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, mount

I have a dual boot set up between Windows 10 and Kubuntu 21.04. I created a new partition on an external hard drive where I store files on Windows (not the boot drive). After I format my partition to ext4, I cannot create any files in it. For some reason, I do see that it creates a folder when I format it called "lost and found". The partition is also mounted. How do I access this new partition I created?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to give my partition read and write permissions. I followed the instructions on this article: https://itsfoss.com/set-write-permission-ext4-partition-ubuntu-linux/ Make sure to replace some of the information in the commands with your own information.